# Persistent Menu and Get Started Button Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm getting to the end of the development process of my bot. I'm currently doing it in C# and the end goal of it is to be deployed on messenger. However I've run into a snag when trying to implement a "Get Started" button and a persistent menu.

The following code was from facebook's dev portal on how to add a persistent menu and I have found similar code for a Get Started button, however, starting my code up in VS Code and pasting this into a terminal, I get an error back complaining about compatibility.

Does Microsoft's bot framework automatically put this in when deploying to the messenger channel or is this code not compatible with C# ?

Thanks

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "persistent_menu":[
        {
          "locale":"default",
          "composer_input_disabled":true,
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"My Account",
              "type":"nested",
              "call_to_actions":[
                {
                  "title":"Pay Bill",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
                },
                {
                  "title":"History",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
                },
                {
                  "title":"Contact Info",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type":"web_url",
              "title":"Latest News",
              "url":"http://petershats.parseapp.com/hat-news",
              "webview_height_ratio":"full"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "locale":"zh_CN",
          "composer_input_disabled":false
        }
      ]
    }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating "persistent menu" and "Get Started button" is specific to Facebook Messenger channel: it is not done through the Bot Framework but they are interesting tools to use in bot framework once they are set up.

This setup must be made with your Facebook development account. All you will have to do after is to handle in your bot code the specific payloads corresponding to your menu or your Get Started action.

So to create your menu and get started button, use your favorite API request tool (in your sample it's made for cURL) to call Facebook's API to setup those items. It has nothing to do with C# or Bot Framework, so nothing is made automatically by the framework.

If you got problems during those calls, please be more explicit about the errors you got.

Comment: Greetings.  Thank you for your reply. So to be clear, only after I've deployed the bot and it's talking back to me,  then I'm able to add stuff like the memu and get started button?  Where is this done? On the Facebook dev page?

Comment: You can do it before your bot deployment, it is indépendant. You can set up those items using API requests, like you mentioned. You will just need to provide identification (token). There may be information about these Facebook messenger settings elsewhere, not on botframework tags

Comment: See examples here: http://thedebuggers.com/persistent-menu-get-started-buttons-bot/